# Match only some integers in a bash script conditional statement

Tags: bash

this is really rudimentary but I'm tired of searching google and I have no idea really what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to construct a bash script that pulls the version number from iOS using sw_vers and then subsequently runs a conditional statement. But the problem is some versions are only two integers and others three. Here's my current script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IOS="`/usr/bin/sw_vers -productVersion`"
    if (("$IOS" >= "5.0")); then
echo "All's good..."
    else
echo "Fail..."
fi
```

With the above script, it pulls the version just fine, but returns a `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0.1 >= 5")` because my specific iOS version is 5.0.1.

I don't care for a perfect match, just the first two integers are fine (so 5.0, 4.2, 4.3, etc.).

I'm sure there's a ton of ways to solve this and I'm not looking for anything fancy. If I can get a wildcard or the script to even ignore anything past the first two numbers, I'm golden.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common techinque is:

```
IFS=. read maj min patch<< EOF
$IOS
EOF

if test $maj -ge 5 && test $min -ge 0; then
    echo ok
fi
```

This will parse $IOS into 3 components, $maj, $min, and $patch.  If IOS is only two components, then $patch will be the empty string.  Note that if either maj or min is not an integer (eg "5a"), a warning will be emitted and the test will fail.  Also, I added the test for $min -ge 0 merely for demonstration, but that could be omitted (unless you may get negative version numbers!).

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
IOS=`/usr/bin/sw_vers -productVersion | awk -F '.' '{ORS=""; print $1; print "."; print $2;}'`
```

or

```
IOS=`/usr/bin/sw_vers -productVersion | cut -d . -f 1,2`
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eugene. I chose to go with William's answer as it was more complete and easier for me to "reverse engineer" in my head. Not because it was any more "right." Thanks for taking the time to come up with one :)

Comment: @cksum - I just +1ed his answer, so I agree with you